# Matrix $A\in M_{3}(\mathbb{Q})$ meet the equation $A^{8} = I$. Prove, that $A^4=I$ and answer, if this matrix can be diagonalized over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me in my second task, where I even don't know how to start

Matrix $A\in M_{3}(\mathbb{Q})$ meet the equation $A^{8} = I$. Prove, that $A^4=I$ and answer, if this matrix can be diagonalized over $\mathbb{Q}$

It's like every matrix to the k-power are always $I$ or $0$  when $k>n$?

Comment: Do you know the [Cayley Hamilton Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)?

Comment: Hm... not, it will help?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest.

Comment: Dear Git Gud, your preceding dialogue with Jonny seems to be lifted from a Marx Brothers  routine. And  I mean this as a compliment ...

Answer (score 7):

If $A^8=I$, the minimal polynomial $\mu_A(t)$ of $A$ divides $t^8-1$. This last polynomial factors as $(t^4-1)(t^4+1)$. Now $\mu_A(t)$ has degree at most $3$, so it must be coprime with $t^4+1$, which is irreducible. It follows that it divides the other factor, $t^4-1$. This tells us, precisely, that $A^4=I$.

Now we know $\mu_A(t)$ divides $t^4-1=(t-1)(t+1)(t^2+1)$. It follows that $\mu_A(t)$ has all its roots simple, so $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$. Over $\mathbb Q$, it is diagonalizable iff all its eigenvalues are rational, and this happens iff $\mu_A(t)$ divides $(t-1)(t+1)$. This is not always the case. For example, consider $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: As for your second question, consider the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Why post it as a comment? I don't see how that helps anyway, the $8^{th}$power of that matrix isn't the identity.

Comment: @GitGud: The second question is «is the $k$th power of an $n\times n$ matrix always zero or the identity if $k>n$?» and my example shows the answer is no...

Comment: I thought you were addressing the diagonalizability. Sorry.